# Spring Security error before logging in

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf 3.0.7 nad Spring security and trying to make a webapp. Logging and creating accounts runs well but before logging (viewing page as anonymous) i'm getting errors as below:

```
2018-07-24 21:09:19.124 [http-bio-8090-exec-7] ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][http-bio-8090-exec-7] Exception processing template "error/general": An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/error/general.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/error/general.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:355)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')" (template: "fragments/layout" - line 34, col 21)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')" (template: "fragments/layout" - line 34, col 21)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:165)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.NegationExpression.executeNegation(NegationExpression.java:149)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.ComplexExpression.executeComplex(ComplexExpression.java:86)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:112)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:125)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardIfTagProcessor.isVisible(StandardIfTagProcessor.java:59)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardConditionalVisibilityTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardConditionalVisibilityTagProcessor.java:61)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1587)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:304)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:278)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:186)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:124)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:109)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authentication object cannot be null
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot.<init>(SecurityExpressionRoot.java:61)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot.<init>(WebSecurityExpressionRoot.java:36)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.createSecurityExpressionRoot(DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.createSecurityExpressionRoot(DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.java:33)
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler.createEvaluationContext(AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.auth.AuthUtils.authorizeUsingAccessExpression(AuthUtils.java:194)
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.auth.Authorization.expression(Authorization.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:106)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:52)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:359)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:89)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:110)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:334)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:263)
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

Since it mentions /WEB-INF/views/error/general.html here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Error page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link href="../../../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link href="../../../resources/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{/resources/css/core.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div th:replace="fragments/layout :: header"></div>
    <div th:replace="fragments/components :: alert (type='danger', message=${errorMessage})">Error: Error</div>
    <div th:replace="fragments/layout :: footer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And layout.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href="../../../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Header -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" th:fragment="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" th:href="@{/}">Demo project</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li th:classappend="${module == 'about' ? 'active' : ''}">
                    <a href="#about" th:href="@{/about}">About</a>
                </li>
                <li th:classappend="${module == 'calendar' ? 'active' : ''}">
                    <a href="#calendar" th:href="@{/event}">Calendar</a>
                </li>
                <li th:classappend="${module == 'event' ? 'active' : ''}"
                    sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"
                >
                    <a href="#event" th:href="@{/addEvent}">Formularz</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li th:if="not ${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}">
                    <a href="/signin" th:href="@{/signin}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Sign in
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}">
                    <a href="/logout" th:href="@{#}" onclick="$('#form').submit();">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;Logout
                    </a>
                    <form style="visibility: hidden" id="form" method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/logout}"></form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<div th:fragment="footer" th:align="center">
    &copy;&nbsp;<span th:text="${#temporals.format(#temporals.createNow(), 'yyyy')}">2017</span>
    Demo project <span th:text="${@environment.getProperty('app.version')}"></span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It says that line

```
<li th:if="not ${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}">
```

is the problem and in fact when i change it to return false no errors are thrown. When i change it to use !isAuthenticated() or isAnonymous() instead of "not [...] isAuthenticated()" it throws errors. I have thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 dependency added in my pom.xml file as well.

My bet is that i have to work on the fact the authenticated object is null. But what else it could be when i'm checking the website as anonymous?

Answer (score 0):

In general you should always have an authentication object on every page of secured application. Filter `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` is responsible for setting `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` in the current security context when it (token) is missing. If this filter is not called it may indicate some problems in security configuration.

BTW try to use `xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"` namespace in your Thymeleaf templates. It will shorten security checks a little bit: `<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">`.